Polars get nth position from Expression type
When I'm aggregating data in polars (e.g. groupby, rolling, group_by_dynamic and calling .agg(...)) how can I get a specific nth position?  (In Polars lingo: How can I select an element within an expression within aggregation?)
Here's a real world example, peak and trough detection.  When detecting a peak you're looking for the value to move up then back down over a rolling window.  Because it needs to go both up and down, the center of the rolling window needs to be checked.
Working code example:
def _detect_peak(x):
    ema = x[0]
    middle_loc = ema.len()//2
    if ema[middle_loc] == ema.max():
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Detect Peak, size is ~7mo before peak and ~7mo after peak, to clearly determine trend.
peak_df = ema_df.group_by_dynamic(col.Date, every=minimum_bar_size, period="14mo").agg(
    Last_Date=col.Date.last(),
    SPX=col.SPX.last(),
    EMA_6mo=col.EMA_6mo.last(),
    Test=col.Date.len()//2,
    Peak_Date=pl.map_groups(col.Date, lambda x: x[0][x[0].len()//2]),
    Peak=pl.map_groups(col.EMA_6mo, lambda x: _detect_peak(x)),
).drop("Date").rename({"Last_Date":"Date"}).unique(subset="Date").sort(by="Date")  # Cut off last rows.

Note: Because this is using date type instead of row count group_by_dynamic is being used instead of rolling. minimum_bar_size is set to a single row's worth of data, so this code for all intents and purposes works just like rolling.
This works.  I solved the problem by writing two map_groups functions, which is slow.
I have two primary questions:

Is there a way to return multiple columns with a single map_groups call so I don't have to call map_groups twice?  Calling it once should in theory double the speed of the code.

How can I access an exact index instead of being limited to first() and last() functions?  I would think Test2=col.Date.list[30], would work but instead it gives the error:



SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected List, got date

Maybe there is a way to convert a date type back into an expression?  If I do Test2=[col.Date.list[30]], I get:

PanicException: called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: InvalidOperation(ErrString("list_builder operation not supported for dtype object"))

From the Polar's documentation found here: https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html#polars.Expr.list.eval

Expression to run. Note that you can select an element with pl.first(), or pl.col()

So it should be supported?  If I paste in their example code Test2=col.Date.list.eval(pl.element().rank()), I get:

SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected List, got date

Maybe it's a bug in Polars?
Updated example: Test2=col.Date.get(1), returns:

OutOfBoundsError: index out of bounds


There is pl.Expr.get.

I tried that. pl.Expr.get is for multi dimensional expressions, like a list of expressions.  It doesn't let you get the nth element within a single expr.

If you have a list of expressions, calling pl.Expr.get on each of the expressions in the list should work. Can you provide a runnable example?

I added an example above, at the bottom of post.

Expr.get (and gather) are supposed to have null_on_oob=True (like .list.getdoes ) so you get null instead of an OutOfBoundsError. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/16842

The result of the aggregation may result in a list, but inside .agg() you do not yet have list[date] type - it is still a date dtype. This is why all the .list.* attempts are producing errors.

@jqurious You would think that .agg(Column_Name=<var>) would accept a single variable type like int, float, date, Decimal, or similar.  I get .first() and .last() return an expr so that they can be chained, but it would be nice if agg columns accepted normal non-expr types as well.  It would make life easier when dealing with edge cases.

Regarding the question in the title.
In general, pl.Expr.get can be used to select values within an expression by index.
However, in a pl.DataFrame.rolling context you'll face the issue of varying window sizes, such that a specific index might be out-of-bounds. Currently, one can workaround this issue, but combining pl.Expr.first / pl.Expr.last with a suitable pl.Expr.shift operation.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"x": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]}).with_row_index()

(
    df
    .rolling(index_column="index", period="3i")
    .agg(
        pl.col("x").alias("x"),
        pl.col("x").first().name.suffix("_first"),
        pl.col("x").shift(-1).first().name.suffix("_second"),
        pl.col("x").last().name.suffix("_last"),
    )
)

shape: (5, 5)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ index ┆ x          ┆ x_first ┆ x_second ┆ x_last │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ u32   ┆ list[i64]  ┆ i64     ┆ i64      ┆ i64    │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 0     ┆ [2]        ┆ 2       ┆ null     ┆ 2      │
│ 1     ┆ [2, 3]     ┆ 2       ┆ 3        ┆ 3      │
│ 2     ┆ [2, 3, 5]  ┆ 2       ┆ 3        ┆ 5      │
│ 3     ┆ [3, 5, 7]  ┆ 3       ┆ 5        ┆ 7      │
│ 4     ┆ [5, 7, 11] ┆ 5       ┆ 7        ┆ 11     │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┘

Regarding your question on the multiple return values.
You can return multiple elements from a call to pl.Expr.map_elements / pl.Expr.map_groups, by returning a dictionary of the values.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("x").map_elements(
        lambda x: {"a": x+1, "b": x+2},
        return_dtype=pl.Struct([
            pl.Field("a", pl.Int64),
            pl.Field("b", pl.Int64),
        ]),
    ).struct.field("*")
)

shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ x   ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
│ 2     ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   │
│ 3     ┆ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   │
│ 4     ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ 13  │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘


Eureka!  Shift works. Test2=col.Date.shift(col.Date.len()//2).last(), gets the midpoint.  I'm surprised I didn't think of it myself.  The info about map_elements return_dtype helps too.  Thank you!

You can write your function to be an expression output so that you don't have to use map_groups.
def _detect_peak(x:pl.Expr)->pl.Expr:
    middle_loc = x.len()//2
    return x.get(middle_loc) == ema.max()

As an aside, if you're calculating the same thing in multiple columns (is. x.len()//2) then you may see performance improvement by using lazy because it'll calculate it once, cache it, then reuse it. In eager mode it'll recalculate it for each invocation.

This will always fail in group_by_dynamic because it will always create a list too small at the tail end (last iteration will always have a list size of 1).  In Github there is a request to make this work (found here) so hopefully in the future your solution will work.
